# Building a specific SQL query

Tags: sql

I have three tables

```
    Employee    
    SSN Name
    1   a
    2   b
    3   c

    Projects    
    Pno Name
    1   x
    2   y
    3   z

    Works_On    
    ESSN    Pno
    1       1
    1       2
    2       1
    3       1
    3       2
    3       3
```

Okay so the question is, how do I know (by query) which employee works on ALL projects. I cant seem to compare multi with multi.

Thank you and sorry for a silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to count all projects, count number of projects for employee and then select all employees that work on the same number of projects:

```
DECLARE @ProjectCount int
SELECT @ProjectCount = Count(*) FROM Projects

SELECT e.* 
FROM Employee e
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Works_On w WHERE w.ESSN = e.SSN) = @ProjectCount
```

`ProjectCount` variable is there to skip counting projects for every employee.

**UPDATE: How it works:**

For each employee count how many records are in `Works_On` table with field `ESSN` equal to current employee's `SSN` and then compare that number to total number of projects.
Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Works_On
```

will give you total number of records in `Works_On` table (6 in your case). We want to count how many records are there for each employee and that's why we embedded that query in our main query with condition to select only records from `Works_On` table that have current employee's `SSN`. If you had to write this in some programming language, this would be logically equivalent to `foreach` loop on employees collection where in body of the loop you select all records from `Works_On` table for current employee and then compare it with total number of projects. If current employee has number of projects equal to the total number of projects, count it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: definitely works!! Thanks, had to remove the variable you created to make it work on mysql. Can you explain how it works? when i run the sub query, it gives me 6 while the project count is 3

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I have expanded the solution with brief explanation. If you still have some questions, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would work on `count`.

```
SELECT e.SSN
FROM Employee e,
     (SELECT w.ESSN, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Works_On w WHERE w.ESSN = e.SSN GROUP BY w.ESSN) wcount,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Projects) p -- you can avoid this by calculating it before. 
WHERE wcount.ESSN = e.SSN
AND p.count = wcount.count
```

Comment: Had a small mistake in it. I have corrected it. Can you try now?

Comment: It's not my question but I'm getting following errors: The multi-part identifier "e.ESSN" could not be bound.

Comment: Still getting: The multi-part identifier "e.SSN" could not be bound.

Comment: yup i can confirm it, its not working same error as above. it seems like a question tht is not as easy as it seems lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Employee.Name, Projects_On
FROM (
    SELECT Works_On.ESSN, COUNT(*) AS [Projects_On] 
    FROM [Works_On] INNER JOIN [Projects] ON Projects.Pno = Works_On.PNO 
    GROUP BY [ESSN]) A 

INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.SSN = Essn
WHERE Projects_On = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Projects)
```

It's not the prettiest query ever but it seems to work.